# Android RSS feeds not clickable

Tags: android, rss

I am working on an Android app that displays RSS feeds from websites, so i downloaded a tutorial from this [website](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/19/android-simplified-source-code-for-parsing-and-working-with-xml-data-and-web-services-in-android/), it has all the code snippets.
And it s working great for me..but when i change the URL of the site that I want my feeds from.. I get the new feeds but I can't click them for details unlike the feeds from the default URL in this tutorial.

Any idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference between the two xml.

Comment: how can i do that? or what to adjust if so?

Comment: can you copy+paste here the 2 feed url?

Comment: default : http://www.gov.hk/en/about/rss/govhkrss.data.xml
desired one : http://www.merehbi.com/online/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=58&Itemid=155&lang=ar&format=feed&type=rss"

Comment: It is possible that your code is looking for CDATA in RSS?
Thats the difference for the 1st look

Comment: Try to cut the <![CDATA[ string form the end of the description tag, and the ]]> from the end. Otherwise, you need to display this as HTML.

Comment: Thank You sir but i guess It's not looking for CDATA

Comment: Thats right, just checked the java source. But, on of those XMLs have HTML in the description tag, and the otherone (what was used in the example project) doesn't.

Comment: i tried this tutorial ( http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/simple-rss-reader-ii-implement-with.html )...now its clickable but as You said only the description isn't shown..of course due to the html in the description tag..

Comment: The problem now is that only the cdata from the xml file isnt being read..which is in my case the description tag
i think i have to use  factory.setCoalescing(true); but dunno how to apply it for this specific tag